# How to solve this problem with pop-ups in Leaflet

Tags: javascript, dictionary, leaflet

I have a website featuring a map with a marker for different places of interest. I am using the js code below that works perfectly :

```
L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
maxZoom: 19,
attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(mymap);
        
//.  t is an array containing gps positions of the different places
for(i=0;i<t.length;i++){
    var marker = L.marker([t[i][lat], t[i][lon]]).addTo(mymap);
}
```

But when I try to add a pop-up for each marker with the code below, the whole map is moved to the left, and not centered anymore on the initial position defined with setView :

```
for(i=0;i<t.length;i++){
    var marker = L.marker([t[i][lat], t[i][lon]]).addTo(mymap);
    marker.bindPopup("<b>mon titre"</b><br>mon texte").openPopup();
}
```

Any idea of what is going on and the best way to solve the problem ?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution : the problem comes from the fact that the pop-ups are open.
Using the following line of code works :

`marker.bindPopup("<b>mon titre"</b><br>mon texte").closePopup();`